# Postgresql: How to query for JSONb arrays containing some value(s)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.2, jsonb

I have this table:

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE lawyer (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  data jsonb
);

INSERT INTO lawyer (data) VALUES
    ('{"a": 1}'),
    ('{"tags":["derecho", "civil", "laboral", "penal"]}'),
    ('{"tags":["derecho", "penal"]}')
;
```

What I want is a JSONb query in postgres for when I need to find fir example any entry that contains "civil" `OR` "derecho"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgres JSONB: query values in JSON array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357971/postgres-jsonb-query-values-in-json-array)

Answer (score 2):

Finally found a way to do this:

Store json arrays directly as top level:

```
INSERT INTO lawyer (data) VALUES
    ('["derecho","laboral","penal"]'),
    ('["derecho", "civil", "laboral", "penal"]'),
    ('["derecho", "penal"]')
;

SELECT * 
FROM lawyer 
WHERE data ? 'penal';
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for an answer for the original data structure, here's the SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM lawyer WHERE lawyer.data->'tags' ? 'penal'
```